# Plotting graph from 2 matrices in Matlab and marking the respective points

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have 2 matrices.

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [100 200 300 400 500]
```

I want to plot these two matrices on a graph. The values from matrix `A` should be on x-axis and `B` matrix should be on Y-axis.  And with that, I also want to mark the respective points on the graph. If I use `plot(A, B)`, it plots the graph correctly. How can I mark these 5 points on the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to do something like this:

```
figure,plot(A, B, '-o');
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't realise it was so simple. Thanks a lot.